# Altering TextView on another View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-viewpager

When altering a TextView on a viewPage the TextView value is never updated.  The reference to it resolves or it seems to but after setting visibility to false or using setText I do not see a change in the View.

I may be going about this all wrong any help is appreciated.

Main.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener 
{
    RelativeLayout layout_joystick;
    RelativeLayout layout_left_right_joy;
    ImageView image_joystick, image_border;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5,     textView6,textView7,textView8,textView9,textView10;
    TextView debugLabel;
    Boolean debug;
    JoyStickClass js;
    RotationStickClass js2;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Removes Title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ViewGroup vi = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab, null, false);

    textView1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    textView6 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    textView7 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    textView8 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    textView9 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    textView10 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView10);

    debugLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.debugLabel);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);

    //Fragment vif = tabPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
    //View vi2 = vif.getView();
    //textView2 = (TextView) vi2.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //textView2.setText("Does this work");

    layout_joystick = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_joystick);
    layout_left_right_joy = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_joystick2);

    js = new JoyStickClass(getApplicationContext(), layout_joystick, R.drawable.image_button);
    js.setStickSize(75, 75);
    js.setLayoutSize(250,250);
    js.setLayoutAlpha(250);
    js.setStickAlpha(100);
    js.setOffset(30);
    js.setMinimumDistance(0);

    js2 = new RotationStickClass(getApplicationContext(), layout_left_right_joy, R.drawable.image_button);
    js2.setStickSize(75, 75);
    js2.setLayoutSize(250, 250);
    js2.setLayoutAlpha(250);
    js2.setStickAlpha(100);
    js2.setOffset(30);
    js2.setMinimumDistance(0);

    layout_joystick.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            js.drawStick(arg1);
            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                textView1.setText("X : " + String.valueOf(js.getX()));
                textView2.setText("Y : " + String.valueOf(js.getY()));
                textView3.setText("Angle : " + String.valueOf(js.getAngle()));
                textView4.setText("Distance : " + String.valueOf(js.getDistance()));

                int direction = js.get8Direction();
                if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UP) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Up");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UPRIGHT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Up Right");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_RIGHT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Right");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNRIGHT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Down Right");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWN) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Down");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNLEFT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Down Left");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_LEFT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Left");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UPLEFT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Up Left");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_NONE) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Center");
                }
            } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                textView1.setText("X :");
                textView2.setText("Y :");
                textView3.setText("Angle :");
                textView4.setText("Distance :");
                textView5.setText("Direction :");
            }
            tabPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            return true;
        }
    });

    layout_left_right_joy.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            js2.drawStick(arg1);
            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                textView6.setText("X : " + String.valueOf(js2.getX()));
                textView7.setText("Y : " + String.valueOf(js2.getY()));
                textView8.setText("Angle : " + String.valueOf(js2.getAngle()));
                textView9.setText("Distance : " + String.valueOf(js2.getDistance()));

                int direction = js2.get8Direction();
                if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UP) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Up");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UPRIGHT) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Up Right");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_RIGHT) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Right");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNRIGHT) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Down Right");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWN) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Down");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNLEFT) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Down Left");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_LEFT) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Left");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UPLEFT) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Up Left");
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_NONE) {
                    textView10.setText("Direction : Center");
                }
            } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                textView6.setText("X :");
                textView7.setText("Y :");
                textView8.setText("Angle :");
                textView9.setText("Distance :");
                textView10.setText("Direction :");
            }
            tabPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
    });

    ImageView imgr2d2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.r2d2);
    imgr2d2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try 
            {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.r2d2);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    debug=true;
    final ImageView imgDebug = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.debug);
    imgDebug.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (debug==true)
            {
                imgDebug.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggle_off);
                debug=false;
                textView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                imgDebug.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggle_on);
                textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                debug=true;
            }

            tabPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

    });
}
        debug=true;
        final ImageView imgDebug = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.debug);
        imgDebug.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if (debug==true)
                {
                    imgDebug.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggle_off);
                    debug=false;
                    textView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    imgDebug.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggle_on);
                    textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    debug=true;
                }

                tabPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

TabPagerAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{
private final List<Fragment> fragmentList;

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
{
    super(fm);
    fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragmentList.add(new FirstTab());
    fragmentList.add(new SecondTab());
    fragmentList.add(new ThirdTab());
}


 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

 @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

FirstTab.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FirstTab extends Fragment 
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#00cd00" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/debugLabel"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Debug"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/debug"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/toggle_on"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_joystick"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image_button_bg" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/r2d2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/r2d2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_joystick2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/left_right_joy" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

first_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DebugRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TextviewLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Y"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Angle"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Distance"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Direction"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TextviewLayout2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Y"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Angle"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Distance"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Direction"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three problems here:

1. After you modify your `TextView` s, you never call `tabPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` which would cause the adapter to refresh.
2. In the `getItem()` method of your adapter you recreate your fragments everytime the method is called. And recreation means that the fragments appear in their original state. Generally you want to avoid recreation in a `ListView`. So either pass a list with your fragments to the adapter or create this list within its constructor.
3. If I am not mistaken calling `invalidate()` on your `ViewGroup` is not necessary.

You should work on your adapter. Maybe this basic implementation will help you.

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    public FragmentsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(new FirstTab());
    fragmentList.add(new SecondTab());
    fragmentList.add(new ThirdTab());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Made the changes you suggested and seems to be doing the same thing I will update my code above to reflect the changes I made.

Comment: I am running the application on the emulator, I have noticed in the past the emulator is quite buggy.... I will side load the apk to my phone and see if it acts the same.

Comment: No joy. acted the same on the phone.

Comment: Okay. Next problem: You want your `TextView` s to be part of the `Fragment`s of your `ViewPager`, right? You have to move *all the functionality* of each fragment into that fragment. This includes getting the references to the `TextView`s and `ImageView`s and their `onClickListener`s and `onTouchListener`s! The point of fragments is to encapsulate functionality independent from an activity so it can be reused in another activity.

Comment: I think I understand, but my Textviews do not have onTouchListeners and currently they are the only things on the Fragment.  the onTouchListeners for the two joysticks are on the main activity below the pageviewer.  I just need the Main activity to communicate with the Textviews on the pager and the pager to update.... So your saying when referencing the Textviews within the main activity I need to call from the adapter and resolve the Textviews that way? much like my commented out code?

Comment: Try putting this into the `onCreate()` method of your main activity (after the creation of the `TextView`s): `Log.d("", textView1 == null?"textView1 is null" : "textView1 is not null");

Comment: textView1 is not null

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "So your saying when referencing the Textviews within the main activity I need to call from the adapter and resolve the Textviews that way?"

Comment: basically I was stating that within my Main Activity I am resolving the Textviews via textView1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); in lieu of resolving the textviews within this manner..... or should I be calling a method from the adapter to obtain the ids.

Comment: IF you need a pager and IF you need to page `Fragment`s for your `TextView`s you will have to get the references of those `TextView`s from your fragments. IF you also need to hold a references to them in your activity, you could instantiate the fragments in the activity, put them in a list and pass that list to the adapter. Instead of doing what I told you to do in the constructur of the adapter you do the same thing in the activity before you pass the list to the adapter.